# React JS website shows elements which should be outside the frame when zooming out on mobile devices

Tags: html, reactjs, mobile, overflow, viewport

I made a website using React, and I have a pseudo page design like in this [video](https://youtu.be/nG2IyH43xMU?si=WT5fP6M_x6EtA6iO&t=284).

The page works fine in a web browser but on mobile if I zoom out I can see the "pages" to the right of the screen border which should be hidden. I was able to prevent users right-scrolling to them by using `overflow-x:hidden`, but zooming out on a mobile device will still allow you to see them.

[Zoomed out page on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgI72.png)

[Intended viewport on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lqcbv.png)

I tried using...

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
```

...in index.html to prevent zooming out. This mostly worked, but it broke `overflow-x:hidden` and the hidden content can still be scrolled to.

How can I code this page to ensure that only the content I want to be visible shows in the frame on mobile devices?